# Trying to deploy a contract on Ganache

Tags: javascript, node.js, ethers.js, ganache

i am trying to deploy a contract in Ganache but having this error

TypeError:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'JsonRpcProvider')
at main (/home/sunny/ether-simple-storage/deploy.js:7:41)
at Object. (/home/sunny/ether-simple-storage/deploy.js:27:1)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Code:

```
  const ethers = require("ethers"); // imports the ethers package
const fs = require("fs-extra");

async function main() {
  const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
    "http://127.0.0.1:7545"
  ); // last node on the blockchain connection

  const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(
    "0x586b0a2c5a92ae7d51a6ec55d56a937433e47eb08b3c2fe4042e72af1557e8c6",
    provider
  ); // connect wallet

  const abi = fs.readFileSync("./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.abi", "utf8");
  const binary = fs.readFileSync(
    "./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.bin",
    "utf8"
  );
  const contractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, binary, wallet);
  console.log("Deploying, please wait...");
  const contract = await contractFactory.deploy({});
  console.log(contract);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Comment: what `ethers` version do you use? does this help? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/144451/typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-jsonrpcprovider

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with the code. Ether.js latest version has the problem use 5.7 version.